# Updating the parameter of Conditional Random Fields without re-training

Tags: image, machine-learning, computer-vision, probability

I am working on a project where we are developing and application for segmentation of foreground object on a mobile device.

Because the segmentation can never be perfect, we are allowing the user to manually adjust the true region after the initial segmentation. The initial segmentation is achieved using pre-trained Conditional Random Field(CRF).

What we want to do further is that once the user adjust the foreground region after the initial segmentation, we want to update the weight parameter of CRF without retraining. However we are not sure if we can achieve this? Is there any approach to do this? Papers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using something like a graph cuts based model, all you would need is to have some hard seeds which would correspond to the user defined regions. For these regions, you can set the unary potentials to infinite and run your CRF inference procedure again. This will not require changing the weights or re-training the CRF.

Comment: I am sorry could you please explain a bit more on your answer. You said that I can set the unary potentials to infinite and run CRF, does that mean using only the smoothness terms for energy minimization? Also I want the model to learn the weights as the user updates the region so that similar objects in future can be segmented with minimum user interaction. Therefore if I dont change the weights, that means the CRF is not learning right?

Comment: I had done some work on this some time back, where we update the seeds and the unary potentials change as more seeds are added (this could even be points selected by the user). You can look into section 3.2, http://www.cs.umd.edu/~bharat/accv2014finalpaper.pdf

Comment: Thanks I will take a look into your paper. Just one question, as you mentioned above about setting unary term to infinite, this is only in the beginning I suppose as later the system will optimize the parameter based on human seeds. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, the unary potentials will get updated because your estimation about what is the foreground is better now. What I did was recompute the GMM including the new pixels, which is then used to re-calculate the unary probabilities.

Comment: Thanks alot for your advise. I am getting the idea now and building my algorithm.

Comment: I got one more question to ask. When training a CRF, do we also need a negative training sample? I am bit confused, though I think only positive samples as ground truth. Is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure what is the training part here, generally training involves learning the weight parameters of clique potentials. I don't think you need to learn that. Just the clique potentials (unary and may some pairwise edges, depending on your model), would change when a user would select a region.

Comment: I meant that when user marks the region, shouldnt I learn the weight that best describes the marked region. Eg. if initial segmentation of the face is without the hair, the user than marks the hair to be in the segmented region, then the CRF should learn this?

Comment: If you can look at the learning weight section in here: http://blog.echen.me/2012/01/03/introduction-to-conditional-random-fields/

Comment: I think it's not part of learning, you just update the potentials once a user marks a new region